# Export the following XML to Datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, httpwebrequest

I'm getting the following XML string using a HttpWebRequest in c#.

**My response XML**

```
<response>
    <accounts>
        <account>
            <city>Some City</city>
            <accountId>1234567</accountId>
            <companyName>My Company</companyName>
            <country>My Country</country>
            <email>myemail@yahoo.com</email>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
        </account>
        <account>
            <city>Some Other City</city>
            <accountId>0987654</accountId>
            <companyName>My Other Company</companyName>
            <country>My Country</country>
            <email>myotheremail@yahoo.com</email>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
        </account>
    </accounts>
    <total>2</total>
    <limit>20</limit>
    <offset>0</offset>
</response>
```

I need to export the XML to a datatable with the following schema.

```
accountId | companyName      | city            | country    | email                  | enabled
1234567   | My Company       | Some City       | My Country | myemail@yahoo.com      | 1
0987654   | My Other Company | Some Other City | My Country | myotheremail@yahoo.com | 1
```

This is my first work with XML and I'm confused how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you read up on LINQ to XML, for example? That's my preferred XML API in .NET, certainly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Forming a DataTable
dt = new DataTable("Accountdata"); // System.Data.DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Account ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Company Name");
dt.Columns.Add("City");
dt.Columns.Add("Country");
dt.Columns.Add("Email");
dt.Columns.Add("Enabled");

// XML Part
string path = "accounts.xml";
XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument(); // System.Xml.XmlDocument
XMLDoc.Load(path);
foreach (XmlNode AccData in XMLDoc.SelectNodes("/response/accounts/account"))
{
    if (AccData["accountId"] == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        // Fill the DataTable line by line
        int AccountId = Convert.ToInt32(AccData["accountId"].InnerText);
        string CompanyName = AccData["companyName"].InnerText;
        string City = AccData["city"].InnerText;
        string Country = AccData["country"].InnerText;
        string Email = AccData["email"].InnerText;
        int Enabled = Convert.ToInt32(AccData["enabled"].InnerText);
        dt.Rows.Add(AccountId, CompanyName, City, Country, Email, Enabled);
    }
}
```

should give you exatly what you want. 
now you have your structure and can further process the data or save it to the database

used classes in focus:

- [MSDN - XmlDocument Class (System.Xml)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- [MSDN - DataTable Class (System.Data)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Comment: `XMLDoc.SelectNodes` is getting error. Error Message : `'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Ahh.. My Bad.. I was using `XDocument` instead `XmlDocument`.. Testing now.

Comment: on wpf: you can simply bind the `DataTable` to the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` to see whats going on.

Comment: Just completed the whole task.. The code above worked as I wanted.. Thanks a lot..